# Is it possible to disable kubernetes dashboard tls check

Tags: kubernetes

I am login kubernetes dashboard in my local machine(`http://kubernetes.dolphin.com:8443/#/login`), and I define a virutal domain name in `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.31.30 kubernetes.dolphin.com
```

and now I am login kubernetes dashboard uing this domain, but it give me tips:

```
Insecure access detected. Sign in will not be available. Access Dashboard securely over HTTPS or using localhost.
```

is it possbile to close kubernetes dashboard(`kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.3`) tls security check in kubernetes dashboard yaml? Because my kubernetes in localhost machine and do not need TLS security.Now my login dashboard look like this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try on `https` instead? like `https://kubernetes.dolphin.com:8443/#/login` and on the not secure screen click Proceed and see if you can login?

Comment: https it give me tips page not found error.@vijay

Comment: Can you check the dashboard pod logs, post the same here?

Comment: logs shows `2020-07-18T06:06:54.534154842Z 2020/07/18 06:06:54 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.@vijay
`

Comment: Can you check out the steps in this thread @Dolphin [kubernetes-dashboard-error-metric-client-health-check-failed-the-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520036/kubernetes-dashboard-error-metric-client-health-check-failed-the-server-coul)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enable kubernetes dahboard http access:

```
containers:
    - name: kubernetes-dashboard
        image: 'kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.3'
        args:
        - '--namespace=default'
        - '--insecure-port=5443'
```

so you could using 5443 port to forward kubernetes dashboard access data, and do not need to login. But you should not do like this in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GitHub docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/common/dashboard-arguments.md) you have to first enable insecure login like so:

```yaml
      containers:
      - args:
        #- "--auto-generate-certificates"  # this must be out 
        - "--enable-insecure-login"
        - "--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0"
        #- "--insecure-port=5443"  # 9090 by deafult
```

and then of course add insecure port mapping:

```yaml
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          protocol: TCP
```

But please bear in mind that it **won't resolve your problem**. Traffic to your dashboard instance **still is not served via HTTPS** from external source. What you ought to do is to use HTTPS connection to the dashboard from your browser using e.g. [self-signed certificates](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-create-and-use-self-signed-ssl-on-nginx/) in NGINX.

Example how to achieve that:

```
server {
    # Secure HTTPS (443) port - self-signed certs
    server_name         localhost;
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /var/www/certbot/nginx-dev.crt; # managed manually, change to your path
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/certbot/nginx-dev.key; # managed manually, change to your path
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location = /favicon.ico { 
        access_log      off; 
        log_not_found   off; 
    }
    
    location /{
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://<cluster-vm-ip>:<api-port>/api/v1/namespaces/<your-namespace>/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:8443/proxy/;
    }
}

server {
    # Insecure HTTP (80) port - permanent redirection to HTTPS
    server_name         localhost;
    listen              80;

    if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    return              404;
}
```

And result (mind that I have a Kubernetes Cluster running in other machine in my private network):

[Kubernetes Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDvgy.png)

Hope that helps!